# Do I need anything between a microcontroller and a basic FM transmitter to cut out EMI?

Tags: microcontroller, emc, transmitter, interference, emi-filtering

Below is my circuit of a basic FM transmitter attached to an output pin of the AT89C2051 micro controller. I haven't tested it and I might decide to connect R1 to the NPN collector instead of to VCC. VCC here is also 5 volts. TP1 is the antenna.

The frequency I will be working with is between 200 and 500Mhz but I might have decided on 350Mhz.

The crystal for the micro-controller will be a low-profile crystal running at about 20Mhz.

What I want to do is limit the EMI produced by the circuit and only have it transmit the data fed from micro controller port P1.7.

Should I adjust the values of C1, C2, or C4? Should I include an LC filter between P1.7 pin and C4? Should I add an additional resistor from VCC to one part of the circuit?

I want the transmitter to be long-range but not to produce EMI.

Any suggestions welcome.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What EMI are you seeing? Or are you guessing it will have noise and are trying to be proactive?

Comment: Can you legally use an unlicenced transmitter on 350 MHz in your area?  What do you mean by "long range"?

Comment: Long range as in approximately a few hundred feet and I checked with regulations and I'm so far safe. I'm guessing the microcontroller will generate EMI noise due to all its processing.

Comment: A shielded enclosure is advised and use a higher voltage for L1

Comment: I'm just curious as to why a higher voltage for L1. Couldn't I use lower value resistors instead to compensate for the current? and what do I put the shielding enclosure on? the IC?

Comment: A radio transmitter produces a radio wave. To "other systems" THIS IS seen as electromagnetic interference. So, when you say "I want the transmitter to be long-range but not to produce EMI" what exactly do you mean? Your circuit as shown will not be compatible with any legal requirements for data transmission from what I can tell so I think you need to recheck regulations in your area. The transmit circuit shown and the method of driving a digital signal to it will generate significant EMI pollution. Why don't you buy licensed modules after all the hard part is designing the receiver.

Comment: I mean I don't want the transmitter to pollute the other frequencies other than the one its intended to transmit on

Comment: If you are mainly concerned about not interfering with other systems, you should shield your whole PCB, but leave an opening for the antenna.